# I need to remove SKU, Inventory, Shipping from vendor dashboard and edit product template in Dokan Pro

Tags: php, wordpress, frontend, dokan

My shop will be selling all digital items
I’m currently on the vendor edit product page of Dokan and there are some options I would like to remove. Such as the description, SEO, Inventory option, linked product, shipping, tax, discount, and other option. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by overriding the template. The file location is dokan-lite/templates/products/new-product-single.php, inventory.php. Follow this post to know how you can override template file via child-theme: https://wpdoctor.press/overriding-dokan-plugin-template-easy/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
.dokan-product-inventory.dokan-edit-row {
        display: none !important;
    }

#dokan-product-list-table td:nth-child(5), 
#dokan-product-list-table td:nth-child(6),
#dokan-product-list-table th:nth-child(5), 
#dokan-product-list-table th:nth-child(6) 
{
    display: none !important;
}
```